# A new version 1.3.61-release-Studio3.6-1 is found but it is not verified by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to start using Android Studio 3.6 beta5 today but my app build.gradle complains:

> A new version 1.3.61-release-Studio3.6-1 is found but it is not verified by Android Studio

What is the problem and how can I make Android Studio use the newer version?

Comment: Having the same issue with `1.4.0-release-Studio4.0-1` :/